# Combined Workday.Intl and IF function

Tags: function, if-statement

Im trying to combine a WORKDAY.INTL and IF function together...

Would like the blue cell to add the orange duration to the green cell but only if the yellow cell is empty.

if the yellow cell has a date, then add the yellow cell and orange duration.

Ive tried combining the functions but just cant get it to work.

Holidays are poart of the WORKDAY.INTL function are the standard set of bank holidays in the UK.  Furthermore, have used "1" to ensure the calculation does not include saturdays and sundays.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are "WORKDAY.INTL and IF functions"? Is this in any way related to any programming language? Then please add the proper tag

Comment: Please include all the material in the question itself, rather than using screenshots. The question should be answerable without having to leave StackOverflow.

Comment: This isn't a free code writing service. What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead?